# 'POST 400 bad request' error during log in parse.com

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

i am doing website and using parse.com as a server. i did a login form and wrote login function in javascript. it worked correctly login button redirected me to profile page, but sometimes after I've got an error message 'POST 400 bad request'  and below it I got this one 'Log in Error:invalid session token' . I have no idea what's going on. I tried to login on different computer and it was successful.

**UPDATE**

```
   function parlogin(){
  var name = $("#name").val(); 
  var pass = $("#password").val();

  Parse.User.logIn(name, pass, {
    success: function(user){


     window.location.href="login/login.html";
    alert("success");
      console.log("everything OK")
    return true;
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
    alert("error");
      console.log("Log in Error:"+error.message);
      return false;
    }
  });

};

var login = document.querySelector('#parslogin');
login.onclick = parlogin;
```

Comment: Could we have a [mcve]?

Comment: The 'status code 400' means [The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1)

Comment: @Siguza i wrote a function which i am using.

Comment: @lonut but it was working first time and after that got this message. also i tried it on different computer and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the login is OK and you do other actions to parse you are somehow getting a stale/bad token used in the Operation to parse.

Below is curl sample from a using stale token in a GET...

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 09:54:52 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.6.0
< X-Parse-Platform: G1
< X-Runtime: 0.034887
< Content-Length: 45
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
{"code":209,"error":"invalid session token"}
* Connection #0 to host api.parse.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```